# Ellipse hit test?

Tags: geometry, hittest, ellipse

What is the optimized (avoiding square roots, trigonometry etc.) formula for hit testing given `x,y` point and ellipse with `cx,cy` center and `width,height`?

*(Ellipse can rotate, but that's not the case.)*

Comment: [This answer on the math site](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/229826/21117) may help.

Comment: And what is the exact reason for downvote?

Comment: sum of distances of (x,y) to the two foci is 2a.

Comment: @madneon Nobody will tell you their exact reason, I'm afraid :-)

Comment: @madneon Wasn't me, but I guess it was due to the apparent lack of research effort.